# How to ensure all links in an email template of some color and cross-client compatible?

Tags: css, email

I am trying to create email template like below

I have the style as in

```
<style type="text/css">
  .rich-text a{color:#ffffff !important;} .ii a[href] { color:#ffffff!important;}
  </style>
```

and inside my template I have as in below

```
 <p class="rich-text" style="color:#ffffff !important;">
    <font color="#ffffff" style="color:#ffffff !important;">
       <xsl:value-of select="body/contents" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </font>
</p>
```

Now the problem is it can contains blob of text including links. Links come out as blue color on some email clients such as gmail. It seems like gmail is stripping out the .rich-text a style I added at the top. How to ensure it gets applied? Basically I want all links in the template to be color white.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but try adding [!important](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

Comment: Different e-mail clients applies styles differently. The only one way which is safety, is inline style. Other styles can be stripped.

Comment: Updated the code with important. That didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Different e-mail clients applies different styles. It's best to use inline CSS. You can check if some style are supported in [this list of most common email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Always remember, that your client may use some extra safe (or old/simple) client that does not support any CSS/HTML and shows it as `text/plain`

Comment: I am unable to directly apply inline styles because links are added as dynamic inside the body/contents.

Comment: I am mostly concerned about Gmail client.

Comment: @HelloWorld replace `<a ` with `<a style="color: #ffffff;"`

Comment: I wish I could @Justinas. I can not because text inside the ``` <xsl:value-of select="body/contents" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> ``` may or may not contain the link or aka the a tag. I am trying to style that link tag if it exists. The body/contents is actually text coming from tiny-mce editor form fields

Comment: @HelloWorld Replace it anyway. If there is no link, nothing will be replaced. Otherwise it will replace text in `<a `